# Java store Objects with UTF 8 characters

Tags: java, utf-8

I would like store store an object that contains UTF-8 data to a file. Unfortunately, nothing I've tried yet does work. I would really appreciate your suggestions. My code looks like that:

```
public static void saveData(MyClass myData) {
    try (FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("data.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs)) {

        ArrayList<MyClass> dataOld = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<MyClass  dataNew = getData();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataOld.size(); i++) {
            dataNew.add(dataOld.get(i));
        }
        dataNew.add(myData);
        os.writeObject(dataNew);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static ArrayList<MyClass> getData() {
    ArrayList<MyClass> data= null;
    try (FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("data.ser"); ObjectInputStream os = new ObjectInputStream(fi)) {

        data= (ArrayList<MyClass>) os.readObject();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return data;
}
```

This solution works for every situation unless I store UTF 8 characters in the objects..

Comment: `String` objects in your `MyClass` objects are not properly encoded ?

Comment: How do you "store UTF 8 characters in the objects"? Do you store `byte`s or `char`s? A `char` is always UTF-16, so how would you get UTF-8?

Comment: How exactly do you "store UTF-8 characters in the objects"? What problem do you see?

Comment: *Does not work* means nothing. Say exactly what is expected and what happens.

Comment: Please provide an example that illustrates the problem; i.e. an example that tries and fails to save UTF-8 characters.  (Looking at your code, I can't see any obvious reason why it *wouldn't* work ...)

Comment: The string elements of MyClass are not properly encoded. I will upload an example as soon as I am back at my PC.

Comment: `ObjectOutputStream` fully supports Strings, they will not "break". So either your input String was already broken (where did you get it from?) or your output String is not properly displayed back to you (how do you do that?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The string elements of MyClass are not properly encoded.

Well, I wouldn't expect them to be.  Strings are serialized as modified UTF-8; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html.  If you tried to look at the data using a standard UTF-8 viewer, the byte counts and other data would most likely "mess up" the text ... to some degree.

(But if the string data doesn't make sense as modified UTF-8, then the problem is that the text in the original strings was already mangled ... )

I think that the real problem here is your expectations.

The data stream produced by `ObjectOutputStream` is binary, not text.  It is not encoded in UTF-8 ... because it is not possible to directly encode an arbitrary stream as UTF-8.   And if you attempted to display / decode `ObjectOutputStream` output as if it was UTF-8, you would get decode errors or garbage.

The solution depends on what you are trying to achieve:

- If you are trying to send an encoded instance of your `MyClass` over a text channel, then what you need to do is to encode the binary stream using something like Base64.  The result won't be legible (human readable) but you will be able to reverse the process and construct `MyClass` instances equivalent to the originals.
- If you are trying to make the output of `ObjectOutputStream` human readable ... it won't work.  The Java object serialization format is fundamentally binary.  If you want the serialized data to be (human) readable, you should use a different serialization format; e.g. JSON or XML.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer; I figured the error out now. The strings I had stored in the MyClass Objects were encoded in ANSI as they originate from a file that uses ANSI and when I created the objects, I did not consider that. It worked fine with normal characters, however, when using spezial characters, the output was just garbage - Even tough the file reader explicitly used UTF-8. Now that the original strings are UTF-8 too, everything works as is should.